# How to escape specific characters with backslash

Tags: ruby

How can I escape reserved characters? I would like this:

```
str = "http://something.tld/"
```

to become something this:

```
http\:\/\/something.tld\/
```

My code below does not work.

```
str.gsub(/(?<foo>[\+\-\&\|\!\(\)\{\}\[\]\^\"\~\*\?\:\\\/])/, '\\k<foo>' )
```

The reserved characters are:

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reserved characters"? I cannot think of a relevant concept that includes the colon in the set.

Comment: The reserved characters are: + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /

Comment: I would like something: from this (1+1)=2  \(1\+1\)=2

Comment: `&&` and `||` are not character, but character-**s**. How should they be escaped?

Comment: I would like to escape an elasticsearch query string. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters

Comment: Don't let us follow the link. Explain it by yourself.

Comment: I use elasticsearch, when I search a "http://something.tld/" the elasticsearch throw an exception, so I need to escape the string, because : and / reserved characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping rules *really* get hairy around this one, but it still ends up rather simple, try

```
str.gsub(/(?<foo>[\+\-\&\|\!\(\)\{\}\[\]\^\"\~\*\?\:\\\/])/, '\\\\\k<foo>' )
```

and you will be given

```
"http\\:\\/\\/something.tld\\/"
```

Don't worry about the double backslashes, they are just `irb`s attempt to visualize that there is a *real* backslash inside this string. If you ask it for its `length` it is `25` which is what you want I think.

Comment: What's with all the backslashes in your regexp? You hardly have to escape anything inside a character class anyway? E.g., `/[+]/ =~ '+'` matches, no need to escape the `+`. This one should be equivalent: `/(?<foo>[-+&|!(){}\[\]^"~*?:\\\/])/`